# How do I combine objective-c classes and 'main' into one file? (CodeEval submission)

Tags: objective-c

CodeEval accepts objective-c programs in one main .m file, but my answer relies on the use of a helper class to do recursive method calls that I've defined. The helper class has a seperate .h and .m file, so I have 3 files total (including my main .m file).  How do I submit them together as one file?

My first thought, was to move the work the methods do over to main, but I cant do that because one of them is recursive and needs to be able to call itself. It doesnt appear that I can define a method outside of a class in objective-c either.

I don't want to re-write my program into main, without recurision, because that would be bad-form.

Is this a limitation to CodeEval's objective-c submissions or is there another way to do this?

Comment: There's nothing that says that a recursive function must be in its own .m.

Comment: Can you elaborate please? How do I define a recursive function and call it within main.m? That was my main question.

Comment: There is no relationship between a file and the code in it.  So long as Xcode knows it's all Objective-C it can be all in one file or a separate file for each class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just put everything in the main.m, like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

// previously in myrecursivecomputer.h
@interface MyRecursiveComputer : NSObject

- (int)fac:(int)x;

@end

// previously in myrecursivecomputer.m
@implementation MyRecursiveComputer

-(int)fac:(int)x
{
    if (x == 0) return 1;
    else return [self fac:x-1] * x;
}

@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        MyRecursiveComputer *c = [MyRecursiveComputer new];

        int f = [c fac:4];
        NSLog(@"Result: %d", f);

    }
    return 0;
}
```